# How to get selected value from dropdownlist in database in asp.net mvc?

Tags: javascript, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get (`agent_name`&`slot_name`) from `tb_agent` & `tb_parkingslot` (ie. selected from 2 dropdownlist) to `tb_freeslot`.Not getting the selected values in `tb_freeslot` instead getting the 2 id's of `agent_name`&`slot_name`.what i need to have these selected values in prescribed db table.

> **Controller**

```
public ActionResult Addagentslot1(FormCollection collection)
        {
            try
            {
             tb_freeslot Addgentslot = new tb_freeslot();
             Addgentslot.slotinfree_name = collection["s"].ToString();
             Addgentslot.agentinfree_name = collection["a"].ToString();
             db.tb_freeslot.Add(Addgentslot);
             int j = db.SaveChanges();
                    if (j > 0)
                    {
                    ViewBag.s = "success";
                        return View();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ViewBag.f = "failed";
                        return View();
                    }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

> **View**

```
    @{
safespot1.Models.SafespotEntities db = new safespot1.Models.SafespotEntities();
    var getag = db.tb_agent.ToList();
    var getsl = db.tb_parkingslots.ToList();
}
<form action="/Admin/Addagentslot1" method="post">
              <select name="a">
                @foreach(var item in getag)
                {
                    <option value="@item.agent_id">@item.agent_name
                    </option>
                }</select>
              <select name="s">
                @foreach (var item in getsl)
                {
                    <option value="@item.slot_id">@item.slot_name
                    </option>
                }</select>
                <input type="submit" value="add space" />
                    <div>
                <label class="label-success">
                    @ViewBag.s
                </label>
                <label class="label-danger">
                    @ViewBag.f
                </label>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: You get the ids because in the drop list options you included the value option as  "@item.agent_id"

Comment: @mbadeveloper yes spotted. when i have another 2 values as `lattitude` `longitude` to pass, what to do?

Comment: Usually you do it this way, setting value to id, then in your postback you build your objects from database with the selected ids.  Html dropdown lists only have a single value so if you want to put more than one field like latitude and longitude into the value you have to do your own custom parsing like:  value = id + "|" + latitude + "|" + longitude.  Then on postback take SelectedValue.Split("|").